# Casting when migrating to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, casting, sdk

I'm working on an old project built on Eclipse and having it opened in Android Studio. Originally built with version 1.7, i'm now on 1.8, having tried 1.7 with no success.

My main problem is i get the 3 following errors:

```
float size = (float) Float.parseFloat(v.getTag(R.string.size));
```

> Error:

```
Error: Error:(228, 71) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

Code:
    int pos = (int) v.getTag(R.string.pos);

```
Error: Error:(229, 49) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int
```

> Code:

```
int parentpos = (int) v.getTag(R.string.parentpos);
```

> Error:

```
Error: Error:(234, 63) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to int
```

I know it is trying to convert an object to integer. I've tried several possible solutions, but had no luck. Any possible changes in the code that i cannot obviously thing about?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v.getTag(R.string.size)` returns an `Object`. It could be any object. You need to cast it explicitly to String

```
float size = (float) Float.parseFloat((String)(v.getTag(R.string.size)));
```

the second and third look weird to me. Casting `Object` to `int`, should be cause a first casting to `Integer`, and then the call to `intValue()` on the casted object.

By the way, android **doesn't** support **java 1.8**

Comment: The first and third are solved, but the second isn't. I don't know if something is wrong, but it shouldn't, as the app was developed by me and a friend around 2 years ago and didn't seem to have a problem back then.

Comment: But the second is equal to the third. It doesn't make any send, does it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you, the full block of code, with first and third replaced is now:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String type = (String) v.getTag(R.string.type);
        float size = (float) Float.parseFloat((String)(v.getTag(R.string.size)));
        int pos = (int) v.getTag(R.string.pos);
        if (type.equals("white")) {
            // Play sound!
            Log.d("DEBUG", "White note, Size: " + size + ", Position (left to right): " + pos);
        } else if (type.equals("black")) {
            int parentpos = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag(R.string.parentpos).toString());
            // Play sound!
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Black note, Size: " + size + ", Parent Position (left to right): " + parentpos + ", Position (top to bottom): " + pos);

        }
    }
```